# Facing issues with Fabric JS in React - trying to add video to Fabric

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, fabricjs

I have a web app where users can select a video from their PC and upload it on the app. Now, with normal Video components and uploads, everything is working fine.

For some particular functionality I need, I see that FabricJS is a really good library with a lot of functionality.

I am trying to add and play the video after uploading it to the web app.

I used code from the Video element example here: http://fabricjs.com/video-element

Here is the function I run after uploading my video:

```js
const fabricFunction = () => {
    try {
      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
        width: 500,
        height: 620,
      });

      var video1 = new fabric.Image(videoRef.current!, {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
      });

      canvas.add(video1);
      (video1.getElement() as HTMLVideoElement).play();
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log(error + "");
    }
  };
```

On uploading a video a video element and a canvas element are shown in the component. On pressing a button, the above function is executed, but nothing happens. The canvas just stays blank.

Here is the complete code of my component:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import { Box, Button, Flex, Spacer, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { fabric } from "fabric";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";

import { useVideoStore } from "@hooks/stores/useVideoStore";
import { Logger } from "@utils/logger";

const VideoComponent = () => {
  const addClips = useVideoStore((state) => state.addClips);
  const clips = useVideoStore((state) => state.videoState.clips);
  const isPlaying = useVideoStore((state) => state.videoState.isPlaying);
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  const onDrop = useCallback(
    (newFiles: File[]) => {
      addClips(newFiles);
    },
    [addClips]
  );
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      videoRef.current?.play();
    } else {
      videoRef.current?.pause();
    }
  }, [isPlaying]);

  const fabricFunction = () => {
    try {
      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
        width: 500,
        height: 620,
      });

      var video1 = new fabric.Image(videoRef.current!, {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
      });

      canvas.add(video1);
      (video1.getElement() as HTMLVideoElement).play();
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log(error + "");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Flex
      flexDir={"column"}
      w={"40%"}
      minW={"40%"}
      bgColor={{ base: "#1A1A1A", md: "#111" }}
      py={"2rem"}
      px={"1.75rem"}
      borderRadius={{ base: "0.5rem", md: "none" }}
      alignItems={(clips ?? []).length > 0 ? "center" : "flex-start"}
    >
      {(clips ?? []).length === 0 ? (
        <>
          <Text
            color={"#FFF"}
            fontSize={"0.875rem"}
            fontWeight={"500"}
            lineHeight={"100%"}
            letterSpacing={"-0.05rem"}
            mb={"1rem"}
          >
            Please upload a video clip to start
          </Text>
          <Flex
            bgColor={"#333333"}
            border={"1px dashed #555"}
            borderRadius={"0.5rem"}
            w={"full"}
            h={"40%"}
            alignItems={"center"}
            justifyContent={"center"}
            {...getRootProps()}
          >
            <Text
              color={"#FFF"}
              fontSize={"1rem"}
              fontWeight={"500"}
              lineHeight={"100%"}
              letterSpacing={"-0.05rem"}
            >
              {isDragActive
                ? "Drop the files here..."
                : "Browser or drag and drop here"}
            </Text>
            <input
              {...getInputProps()}
              type="file"
              accept=".mp4,.mov"
              multiple
            />
          </Flex>
        </>
      ) : (
        clips?.map((videoClip, index) => (
          <Box key={index}>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="620"></canvas>
            <video
              ref={videoRef}
              width={"50%"}
              src={`${URL.createObjectURL(videoClip)}`}
              muted
              style={{
                display: "none",
              }}
            />
            <Button onClick={fabricFunction}>Test Filters</Button>
          </Box>
        ))
      )}
      <Spacer />
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default VideoEditingSidebar;
```